# Wrapping a character code for a Caesar Cipher

Tags: clojure, caesar-cipher

I'm writing a Caesar Cipher. To deal with characters being shifted to outside of the "normal" printable ASCII range (`[32 126]`), I'm having them "wrapped" to the max/min in the range.

My current solution works, but it has a couple issues:

- It involves a couple repeated lines. The `(- max-code (rem (- max-code char-code) code-range))` part is basically the same in both places, just with a few minor differences. If I really wanted to reduce repetition, I could bind a function that encapsulated the similar parts, and pass in the parts that vary, but I can see that being overly complicated for something so simple.
- I have the "in-range" case as the last one, but in reality, since it's likely to be the most common case, it should be the first checked. Is the compiler capable of doing an optimization to account for this? Is this even something I should worry about? This only seems like an issue because this will be one of the most called functions in my program, so it has the potential to become a bottle-neck (although I haven't profiled it yet).

Since I'm still learning Clojure, any recommendations to make my code simpler or more idiomatic would be appreciated.

---

```
(defn wrap-shifted-code [^long char-code]
  (let [min-code 32
        max-code 126
        code-range (- max-code min-code)]
    (cond
      (< char-code min-code) (- max-code (rem (- min-code char-code) code-range))
      (> char-code max-code) (+ min-code (rem (- char-code max-code) code-range))
      :else char-code)))
```

---

At the request of @Sam Estep, here's a version of the code that correctly includes the outer bounds of the range when wrapping:

```
(defn wrap-shifted-code [^long char-code]
  (let [min-code 32
        max-code 126
        code-range (- max-code min-code)]
    (cond
      (< char-code min-code) (- max-code (rem (- min-code char-code 1) code-range))
      (> char-code max-code) (+ min-code (rem (- char-code max-code 1) code-range))
      :else char-code)))
```

Comment: By `[32 126]`, you mean `(range 32 (inc 126))`, right? In that case, shouldn't `(mapv wrap-shifted-code [31 127])` be `[126 32]` instead of `[125 33]`?

Comment: @SamEstep `[32 126]` is an inclusive interval. I'm not including the delete character at 127.

Comment: @SamEstep Unless I missed the point of your question.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I would expect that 31 (the character immediately before the start of the range) would map to 126 (the character at the end of the range) and that 127 (the character immediately after the end of the range) would map to 32 (the character at the start of the range), but they don't.

Comment: @SamEstep Oh ya. It's like that since originally, the way I tried to use to correct for that created a offset bug if the function was called with a `shift-to` greater than the character range (94). I've fixed that since posting this.

Comment: If the code in your question is incorrect, could you please correct it?

Comment: @SamEstep Well, technically it works fine, it just doesn't work as you'd intuitively expect. It's generally frowned upon to change code once it's posted.

Comment: It's also generally frowned upon to post code that doesn't do what it's supposed to do. Do you want answers with code that replicates the exact behavior of the code you've posted in your question, or do you want answers with code that does what you specified in the description part of your question? If the latter, you should fix the code in your question. Or at the very least, add a note at the end of your question with the fixed code.

Comment: @SamEstep I'll update the question when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions have subtle off-by-one errors. Your second solution partially fixes these by adding 1 to the result in some cases, but it doesn't fix the real problem, which is this:

```
(let [,,,
      code-range (- max-code min-code)]
  ,,,)
```

`code-range` needs to hold the number of integers from 32 to 126, inclusive. As [Dijkstra famously noted](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), calculating this number is easy when you're using an inclusive-exclusive range, but when your range is inclusive on both ends, you need to account for that by adding 1:

```
(let [,,,
      code-range (- (inc max-code) min-code)]
  ,,,)
```

In response to your questions about repetition and performance: there's a function for that! Unlike [`rem`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rem), Clojure's [`mod`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mod) function always returns a nonnegative value, so you can do this:

```
(defn wrap-shifted-code [char-code]
  (let [min-code 32
        max-code 126
        code-range (- (inc max-code) min-code)]
    (-> char-code (- min-code) (mod code-range) (+ min-code))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tested thoroughly to ensure it was correct, but I realized after that I was accidently correcting for the error during my test. And good call on the second part; that's significantly better. I should force myself you use the thread macros more often to get used to using them. `->>` seems to basically be like Haskell's composition (kinda-sorta), so conceptually it's not that difficult.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well, you can do function composition in Clojure using [`comp`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp), but since Clojure doesn't have implicit currying (you have to use [`partial`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) instead), it's usually more concise to use the threading macros.